# Haskell - Print a Trace After Execution

Tags: haskell, io, monads, trace, side-effects

I have a project for Uni to write a compiler (in Haskell) for a simple made-up imperative language. One of the requirements is printing debug statements on entering a function call, leaving a function and assigning variables.

Printing messages when entering functions is easy, I just use Debug.trace, eg:

```
functionValue = trace "Entering function" (evaluateFunction functionArguments)
```

The same process applies when assigning to variables. What I can't figure out is how to print when returning from a function call and have the output timed correctly with the other outputs. Every attempt I've made so far has resulted in "Leaving function" being printed immediately after "Entering function" - I need the function's internal debug statements (assigning and nested function calls) to be printed before "Leaving function" is printed.

My imperative habits tell me that I need a way to force execution of (evaluateFunction functionArguments) before the leave-function output, but this seems impossible and wrong in Haskell.

Example output I get now:

```
Entering main function...
Leaving main function...
Entering fn1 function...
Leaving fn1 function...
Assigning value1 to A.
Assigning value2 to C.
Entering fn2 function...
Leaving fn2 function...
Assigning value3 to B.
Assigning value4 to C.
```

Same program's output the way I need it to look:

```
Entering main function...
Entering fn1 function...
Assigning value1 to A.
Leaving fn1 function...
Assigning value2 to C.
Entering fn2 function...
Assigning value3 to B.
Assigning value4 to C.
Leaving fn2 function...
Leaving main function...
```

So, what's Haskell idiom for 'run myFunctionWithTraces then print myString'?

Comment: As you need to guarantee messages are printed in a specific order, you should not use Debug.Trace. Instead, bite the bullet, run in IO, and use `putStrLn` or similar.

Comment: Are you compiling to Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to immediately print traces, you can lift the function to IO monad, and put it between two `putStr`s, e.g.

```
trace :: String -> IO () -> IO ()
trace name f = do
    putStrLn $ "Entering " ++ name
    f
    putStrLn $ "Leaving " ++ name
```

And then:

```
main = trace "main" $ do
    fn1
    fn2

fn1 = trace "fn1" $ do
    return ()

fn2 = trace "fn2" $ do
    return ()
```

This also can be done purely, with the [`Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.0.1.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html) monad (i.e. don't print, but just accumulate debugging output as you go). `trace` would then look more like this:

```
trace :: String -> Writer String () -> Writer String ()
trace name f = do
    tell $ "Entering " ++ name ++ "\n"
    f
    tell $ "Leaving " ++ name ++ "\n"
```

and with additional step of unwrapping the debug output with `runWriter` or `execWriter`.

Edit: generalising `trace` to `IO a` is not too difficult:

```
trace :: String -> IO a -> IO a
trace name f = do
    putStrLn $ "Entering " ++ name
    ret <- f
    putStrLn $ "Leaving " ++ name
    return ret

main = trace "main" $ do
    a <- fn1
    b <- fn2
    print $ a + b

fn1 = trace "fn1" $ do
    return 42

fn2 = trace "fn2" $ do
    return 69
```

Answer (score 1):

[The code was unreadable in a comment so I posted another answer as a comment to Cat Plus Plus]

I've finally threaded the IO monad through all my code, but this solution doesn't quite work - I need to get return values (ie. IO (value)) out of my functions.

```
do
    putStrLn $ "Entering " ++ name
    f
    putStrLn $ "Leaving " ++ name
```

The above snippet will return IO () (the empty IO monad). So I modified it to be:

```
do
    putStrLn $ "Entering " ++ name
    returnVal <- f
    putStrLn $ "Leaving " ++ name
    return (returnVal)
```

<strike>But this is now printing:</strike>

inside function actions...
...
...
Entering function
Leaving function

Edit: The incorrect output was getting was my fault: I accidentally put `result <- f` *before*  `putStrLn "Entering...`